# How to test method alias ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

How to test if if method has an alias?

Let's say we have

```
Class Test
  class << self
    def a;end
    alias :b :a
  end
end
```

so far I came up with idea to write this spec:

```
it { expect(Test.b).to receive(:a) }
```

but I believe there is better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Should method aliases even be tested? https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/1962

Comment: @chemturion years after asking this question, years of writing countless tests in RSpec I can definitely say that you shouldn't :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-method).

```
Test.method(:b) == Test.method(:a)
```

Comment: To use this on a `Test` instance method: `Test.new.method(:b) == Test.new.method(:a)`

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
expect(obj.method(:method)).to eq(obj.method(:alias))
```

Answer (score 7):

[oldergod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004274/oldergod)'s answer works in most scenarios:

```rb
Test.method(:b) == Test.method(:a)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work in Ruby 2.3+ when **the two methods have different owners** (e.g. when the method is defined in a module, and the alias is defined in a class that includes the module). This is because [the behavior of `Method#==` changed in Ruby 2.3](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7613#change-35118):

> If owners of methods are different, the behavior of `super` is different in the methods, so `Method#==` should not return true for the methods.

If you find yourself in this situation, where you want to test that two methods are aliases of each other but they have different owners, you can use `Method#original_name` or `Method#source_location` instead:

```rb
Test.method(:b).original_name == Test.method(:a).original_name
Test.method(:b).source_location == Test.method(:a).source_location
```

Comment: I found out that it doesn't work at all in Ruby 2.7.

Answer (score -4):

You can set a result to your function to check if result is same.

```
def a
  return 'test string'
end
```

then
    it { expect(Test.b).to eq(Test.a) }

is it ok?

Comment: Same result doesn't mean it's an alias.