# How to test `alias_method`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a class as follows:

```
class User
  alias_method :nickname, :username

  def username
    self.name.split(' ').first.downcase
  end
end
```

I would like to test that the method `:nickname` is an alias for `:username`.

Both the following don't work:

```
user = User.new
User.instance_method(:nick_name) == User.instance_method(:username)
user.method(:nick_name) == user.method(:username)
```

A similar discussion happened at [How to test method alias ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883618/how-to-test-method-alias-ruby) , but the answers stated there don't work.

Comment: Works for me, the `alias_method` needs to be after the username definition though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you shared the link for discusses about `class` methods, here you have instance methods. and yes, as correctly pointed out by @HoMan in the comments, following should work..

```
class User
  def username
    self.name.split(' ').first.downcase
  end

  alias nickname, username
end
```

In you testcases,

```
user = User.last
user.nick_name == user.username
```

Comment: This only works if the method being aliased does not have side effects.