# Object#method in Ruby 2.3+ for aliases through included modules behaves differently

Tags: ruby

Following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25883691/6728018) I wrote some specs that use `Object#method` to test that a method was properly aliased. In some cases the class is aliasing a method the comes from an included module. This works for me in 2.2 but not in 2.3 and 2.4

I did some experimentation and the difference can be boiled down to this:

```rb
module Foo
  def foo
  end
  alias_method :foo_foo, :foo
end

class Bar
  include Foo
  alias_method :bar, :foo
end

bar = Bar.new
bar.method(:foo) == bar.method(:bar)
# true in Ruby 2.2
# false in Ruby 2.3+

bar.method(:foo) == bar.method(:foo_foo)
# true in Ruby 2.2+
```

Does anyone know if this was an intentional change in Ruby 2.3? If so, what's going on here?

I specifically tested 2.2.3, 2.2.7, 2.3.0, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, and 2.4.1.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ [`Method#original_name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Method.html#method-i-original_name) seems to be a better fit to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an intentional change in Ruby 2.3.

The reason is that `Method#==` returns false if the owners are different. From [the bug discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7613#change-35118):

> If owners of methods are different, the behavior of `super` is different in the methods, so `Method#==` should not return true for the methods.

As [mudasobwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa) pointed out, `Method#original_name` is a good alternative for this situation. `Method#source_location` seems like another robust option.